# EmberJS Routing with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-old-router

From a rails .erb I can call an Emberjs view and it renders fine:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{ view App.ListUsers }}
</script>
```

Now if I were to use the core statemanager, I'd make something like this:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    index: Ember.State.extend({
      route: '/'
});
```

How might I call the the index route directly from a .erb?  Like a bootstrap to start the emberjs app.

I'm looking to use Ember for an administration dashboard so I will fire up the emberjs app after an admin logs into the rails app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```js
Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/'
      // connectOutlets and such...
    })
  }),
```

From the Ember.Router dochttp://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html:

> The initialState property of `Ember.Router` instances is named `root`.

Comment: Good call, but that doesn't completely answer my question.

If I have a rails view, how do I tie the rails view with that specific route in erb.  Is there a call I can use in handlebars to call that route without user interaction?